# Статистика по регистрации клиентов в мобильном приложении

Tags: android-studio, статистика, playmarket

Рекламирую android приложение вк, инстаграмм. Для установки указана ссылка на play market.

Как можно и можно ли получить статистику по какой рекламе пришли клиенты и в каком количестве?